# Voltage Drop Across MOSFET in Ground path

Tags: mosfet

I have an arrangement in which an NMOS is connected in the ground path to control the power flow as shown below :-

[image]

When the FET is on , current will flow & there has to be voltage drop across the mosfet. Because it is connected on 0V already, how to analyze the voltage drop across it?

Comment: Look up its Rdson value and treat it as a resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an NMOS is connected in the ground path the control the power flow

It's worth mentioning that when the FET is "off" current will flow through the diode - is this what you really want?

If so then just do as pjc50 says and treat the MOSFET as a resistor equal to its on-resistance.

Looking at your circuit a bit more, all it realistically does is protect the load from reverse polarity inputs.

Comment: yes Andy, you are correct. My intent is to understand the voltage drop. If , i am driving with 5V/2A  & ground is obviously @ 0V. What will be the voltage before & after the Mosfet if RDSon is 10mohm & MOSFET is in on state.

Comment: How much current does your load take? It's just ohms law realistically.

Comment: @Rishi: Andy is telling you that your circuit **will never turn off**. Look at the diode in the FET. It will conduct when the FET is off. You have the FET in backwards.

Comment: The FET isn't backwards, it's being used for polarity protection rather than switching.

Comment: except read his question: "when the FET is on..." if the voltage is correctly applied -> via diode AND FET "on". If voltage is incorrectly applied FET is off and diode blocks. The FET is only gated for the correct polarity. Blocking can be done with a simple diode.

Comment: @JonRB it can be done with a simple diode but is much more effective using a MOSFET because the MOSFET will shunt the diode to a very low volt drop (providing the gate gets enough voltage (but not too much)).

Comment: I know diode is conducting. Lets assume that the FET is placed in reverse direction . Now, Current is 2A. So if RDSon is 10mohm. Voltage Drop is 2V. So, considering this , how will the ground shift? Before & after the FET, will it be 2V & 0V or 0V & -2V?? How to analyze voltage drop when voltage is 0V i.e ground?

Comment: Eh?????? 10 milli ohm and 2A is 20 milli volts.

Comment: oops, yes. So, how to analyze this 20mV drop on 0V line. Where will this shift happen?

Comment: @Andyaka The FET is an Ntype if I am reading the arrow correctly (bit small) so with an external diode in-place the FET is moot as the SOURCE is the load side so it cannot shunt current when the PSU is supplied correctly.

Comment: The source is initially only a diode drop away from incoming 0V and the gate is several volts above this, therefore the MOSFET will turn on. Look at this link and note that there is at least one N channel example: https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+protection+mosfet&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii__Px6arOAhUrBsAKHWmODlUQsAQIKQ&biw=1275&bih=897

Comment: @Rishi the loads most negative wire will be 20 mV higher than the incoming supply's most negative wire.

Comment: ohh greatt!! Thank you Andy. Is there any document explaining this phenomenon?

Comment: It's ohms law - just replace the MOSFET with a 10 milli ohm resistor in parallel with the diode and there you have it.